# In C, can I put off the "typedef" of a header file until I include and use the header file?

Tags: c, generics, include, typedef

I have 2 files: `stack.h` and `stack.c`. Both of them have a undefined type `elem_type`.

So my question is: **Can I leave them undefined until I include the stack.h and then give it a definition depended on the need of the calling file ?**

Comment: It depends a good deal on the use of `elem_type`. If you need something more than a pointer, the answer is "no"; pointers `elem_type *ptr` and array-typed function parameters `void foo(elem_type element[])`are OK, though.

Comment: Ii is not fully clear what your problem is (we have to guess a bit) and if it can be solved. I suggest to show sample files `stack.c` and `stack.c` (and if necessary a 3rd file that uses them) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I had another file called `stack_elem_type.h` to define the `elem_type`. But I have foud it is barely useless for the `stack_elem_type.h` that  if I have more than 1 file which include `stack.h` and have data of different types to push into the stack. So I wonder whether I can put off the definition of the `elem_type`.

Comment: @JoeNahm Please [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification there instead of answering in comments. Without seeing the actual code from `stack.c` (or relevant parts of it) it is difficult to give a good answer. What you want may be possible if your functions could be changed to take only pointers to `elem_type` in accompanied by the structure size.

Comment: Unless you play with macros, your code using the functions from `stack.c` can only be used with one element type in your program — because the function names will be fixed.  If you need to handle multiple types of different sizes in different stacks, you have to write more generic code (taking `void *` addresses to elements and a size) and write the stack (carefully — does the stack own the data, or does it need to make a copy of the data) to work with those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot leave undefined type in stack.c in C because when a compiler tries to compile stack.c it won't be able to determine the type.

In C++ this is feasible via template.